# Python - Split string with several different multicharacter delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I want to split the string `"You Ain't Seen Nothing Yet - Remastered 2009 (With Vocals)"` into `["You Ain't Seen Nothing Yet", "Remastered 2009", "With Vocals)"]`. In other words, I want the delimiters to be `" - "` and `" ("`. My attempt:

```
import re
song_name = "You Ain't Seen Nothing Yet - Remastered 2009 (With Vocals)"
song_name = re.split(r'[\s\-\s|\s\(]+', song_name)
print(song_name)
```

However, this results in splitting on a single space as well: `['You', "Ain't", 'Seen', 'Nothing', 'Yet', 'Remastered', '2009', 'With', 'Vocals)']`

How do I specify that I ONLY want to split on `" - "` and `" ("` using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
\s+(?:-\s+|\()
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/mMsCe7/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##VYxBCsIwFAX3PcWjmyRopehKQcQLuFBQCgUp@mkCzU9IvgvBu0dXiquBYZj4FBt4VYrzMSRBoioHHq88eMIWdRce2DtWghMR4xDEOh7RkaDBkfyQhRLdsWzbNfTFicU53IYpm/pvlGiR4@REJ9Xnmd5tmg9evTZqjm9nqpgci/6JUt4):

```py
import re
song_name = "You Ain't Seen Nothing Yet - Remastered 2009 (With Vocals)"
song_name = re.split(r'\s+(?:-\s+|\()', song_name)
print(song_name)
```